# MySQL ORDER BY extremely slow. How to optimize?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization, bigdata

I am looking for a solution for my problem with extremely slow queries and I hope you can help me.

First of all, what I want to do is the following:
I've got a table, lets name it *item_table* with some information about goods. Every item has an *orderid*. The problem here is: this order id is **not unique**.
Every change of an item is such to say "progressively" recorded. Here is an example:

```
             order_id     max_vol   remain_vol
Purchase 1   2007468329   8753      4126
Purchase 2   2007468329   8753      4122
Purchase 3   2007468329   8753      4006
```

**To explain that a bit:**
Every time a person buys an item there is a new entry with the same order id and a changed remaining volume (*remain_vol*). The *max_vol* is the total volume which the seller entered on stock at beginning. An item can have multiple order ids, but everytime a seller inserts something (even if it is the same item) it gets a new order id.

**What I now want to do is the following:**
I want to get the item with the most sold units. That means I only want to get the difference between `MAX(remain_vol)` and `MIN(remain_vol)` and I only want to get items where anything got sold `(=max_vol != remain_vol)`

**To get a bit more specific:**
Here is the create table for my data table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `data` (    
    `orderid` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,    
    `regionid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,    
    `systemid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `stationid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `typeid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `bid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `price` float DEFAULT NULL,
    `minvolume` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `volremain` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `volenter` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `issued` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `duration` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
    `range` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `reportedby` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `reportedtime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      KEY `orderid` (`orderid`) USING BTREE,
      KEY `volremain` (`volremain`) USING BTREE,
      KEY `volenter` (`volenter`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The column *max_row* I mentioned is in the table *volenter*, *remain_vol* is *volremain*.

This table contains **about 60 million entries**.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?
I already tried some queries but they all take ages to execute.

Kind regards and hoping for a solution
- Lyrex

Comment: What SQL sre you trying to optimize?

Comment: Have you set up any indexing?

Comment: @AlmaDo I am using MySQL 5.6.16.

Comment: @WillP. As you can see I've set up Keys on orderid, volremain and volenter. I do not have a primary key.

Comment: ic, also I think Alma meant what query are you trying to optimize

Comment: My first try was this query:  

`SELECT orderid, volenter, MIN(volremain), (MAX(volenter) - MIN(volremain)) AS absolute_vol_dif, MAX(volremain) - MIN(volremain) AS relative_vol_dif, issued, duration FROM data GROUP BY orderid HAVING absolute_vol_dif > 0 AND relative_vol_dif > 0;`

Comment: What does an explain show? How often do you update this table?  If you can't optimize the the SQL for whatever reason, maybe have a post-load job that stores the results of your base query in a summary table.

Comment: Q: your "Items_Table" having information about goods (assuming stock activity), is the order a 1 to 1 for a single thing, or are there multiple "things" an order can be associated with. --- just to confirm before I write something up.

Comment: @DRapp An order id is associated with one "stack" of items. Lets assume a seller inserted 3000 pieces of an items - this stack gets an own order id. ```volenter``` stands for the numer of items the seller originally inserted and ```volremain``` is what's left out of it.

Comment: @Andrew here's the result for an explain: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Kr705qPY I do update the table once a day because I fetch the updates from the API everyday one time. As I explained, I get once a day a new CSV file which contains all entried. My table has the same format as the CSV.

Comment: @Lyrex, yes, one "stack" of items, but are the items all the same.  Ex: Someone buying Apple stock (or selling), would be an order of say... 500 shares of "AAPL". where ALL the "items" are the same thing? and not an "order" of 500 and the things are Apple, Google, Amazon within a single order.

Comment: As someone else pointed out, you have no constraints.  Do you really want to spin through every single row?  In any case, assuming you will be querying this data repeatedly, I still would suggest building a summary table where you collapse each order to a single row.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the way your table is structured. When a user buys an item you shouldn't be appending a new entry to the table. There are many things wrong with this approach.

First of all, orders should have a unique order ID, unless there's a really good reason not to. What you should do instead is make order ID unique, and give it the fields `init_vol`, `max_vol`, and `sold`. When a user buys an item, you increment the field `sold`. When you want to get the most sold units, you order by `sold` descending.

This way you are not growing the table unnecessarily. All your queries become much simpler and faster.

Comment: My problem here is that I get the whole data from an API and I just want to process them. I don't like the structure, too, but I do not have any influence on how I get those data. I could pre-process it after fetching those, but it's anyways one time I have to process them as they are.

Answer (score 0):

Per Questions asked, and a little bit of assumptions, hopefully this answer can help you.

I would create a covering index on your data table of

```
( typeid, orderid, remain_vol )
```

Not knowing the basis of the columns, I am assuming (yeah I know assume), that the TYPEID is some sort of indicator as to a buy OR sell.  if you are looking only for 'sell', then this can help the query.  By also having the orderid will help the grouping, and the remain_vol column prevents the need to go back to the raw data pages to apply your query.

I would also have a covering index on your "item_table" too something like

```
(orderid, item)
```

so it can be efficiently joined to the result sell orders, and the item (such as stock name)
can be there too for quick reference without going to the raw data pages.

That said, I would then try something like

```
SELECT
      t.item,
      SUM( PreAgg.MaxVol ) as TotalVolPerItem,
      SUM( PreAgg.MinVol ) as TotalRemainingToSell
   from
      item_table t
      JOIN (SELECT
                  d.orderid,
                  MAX( d.remain_vol ) as MaxVol,
                  MIN( d.remain_vol ) as MinVol
               from
                  data d
               where
                  d.typeid = 'sell'  (or whatever flag indicator if this is correct assumption)
               group by
                  d.orderid
               having
                  MIN( d.remain_vol ) > 0 ) PreAgg
         ON t.orderid = PreAgg.orderID
   group by
      t.item
```

The "HAVING" clause is based on the minimum remaining value having something left.  Ex, if the order was for 500 of something and gradually sold off to 400, 300, 200, 150, 76,  the amount remaining of 76 would be one you are considering.

Comment: As I already posted I can not take influence on the data I get. I get it from an API as CSV. What I also should mention: The 60 million entries are not gathered over years. They are gathered in less than a week. That's my major problem.